Help understanding SharePoint 2019 and Keycloak IDP
I'm a little confused about how to accomplish this and need guidance on deployment setup.
I've got multiple AD domains using ADFS to authenticate to Keycloak. When you go to the Keycloak login page, the users can log in with their IDPs.
What I can't find documentation on is how to get this keycloak user to authenticate into my on-prem SharePoint. I've looked at this document for help. But this is where I get confused. Am I setting up another ADFS relaying trust on the Sharepoint server and connecting that to the "Clients" in Keycloak or do I setup a New-SPTrustedIdentityTokenIssuer and connect that to keycloak?
Any clarification would be helpful.
